# Calculating time elapsed within grouped sets of rows

Tags: r, datetime

I know there are many stackoverflow pages asking about calculating date-time differences between rows but I have not found one that answers my particular question. Most are interested in data between subsequent rows but I need to calculate for a series of individuals how much time has elapsed for each individual. For example

```
id      time (of the day)
1       12:00:40
1       12:06:35
1       12:12:00
2       14:59:22
2       15:10:40
```

I would like to calculate something that looks like this:

```
   id      total time (seconds)
    1       760
    2       678
```

Thanks in advance for help and I apologize if this has been answered somewhere else, I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete base R approach

```
aggregate(time~id, transform(df, time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%H:%M:%S")), 
                   function(x) sum(as.numeric(diff(x), "secs")))

#  id time
#1  1  680
#2  2  678
```

---

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`, we first convert `time` to `Period` class and convert it into seconds and take the `sum` of its difference.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(total_time = sum(diff(seconds(hms(time)))))


#    id   total_time
#   <int>      <dbl>
#1     1        680
#2     2        678
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` approach

First set the time-string to a POSIXct-format, so you can use functions like `difftime`. This comes in handy when an id had a timespan over more than 1 day (say from 22h untill 02h)
Second step is to calculate the difftime (in seconds) between the minimum time-value and the maximum time-value (by id-group)

```
library( data.table )

dt <- fread("id      time
1       12:00:40
1       12:06:35
1       12:12:00
2       14:59:22
2       15:10:40", header = TRUE)

#set time to POSIXct
dt[, time := as.POSIXct( paste0( "2019-01-01 ", time ), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ) ]
dt[, .( total_time = difftime( max( time ), min( time ), units = "secs" )), by = .( id ) ]

#    id total_time
# 1:  1   680 secs
# 2:  2   678 secs
```

Comment: Given that you use `data.table`, an alternative may be to use its `ITime` class, which is second based: `dt[ , time := as.ITime(time)]`; `dt[ , max(time) - min(time), id]`

Comment: @Henrik never heard of that class. learning more wvery day, thanks!